# Chrome Remote Desktop - Using Windows key functions from 1 desktop to another

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, google-chrome-app

I'm currently connected to one of my Windows 7 desktops from another Windows 7 desktop through Google Chrome Remote Desktop application. My current issue is that because it runs in the Chrome browser, whenever I try to use Windows functions (Windows + L to lock for example) it issues the commands on the desktop that I am remote connecting FROM, and not the desktop which I am remote connecting TO.

Quick example: I am connecting to one of my desktops and wish to instantly lock. I press Windows + L and the PC I am connecting through locks instead of the computer I am remote connecting to.

Does anyone know of any work around?

I have seen that Chrome supplies a couple of 'send keys' e.g. CTRL+ALT+DEL and Prtscn, it would also be really useful if you could add personalised send keys, and have looked everywhere bit can't seem to find the option to create send keys.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks all,

Dave

Comment: What a contrived idea and constraint.  I have been programming for 35 years to the day, and my opnion is that google remote desktop is very much a tool used by programmers for programming.  How about focus on code instead of religious ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to use Win + ___ commands is to get it through the start menu. There is a check option to use right Ctrl as Win key, but it doesn't record multiple key presses. It sends it once when you let the key go, making it impossible to use multi key commands.

So when I want to lock the computer, I do it through the start menu.